# Using HttpContext outside of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

```
public class UserAccount
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

  public UserAccount(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  //Sign in
  public static async Task SignIn(dynamic user)
  {
    var claims = new[]
    {
      new Claim("UserID", user.ID.ToString()),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Baller")
    };

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
          new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", principal);
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error from the await statement in the SignIn method:  **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "UserAccount._httpContextAccessor"**

The error disappears if I don't declare the method as static, however from my controllers I can't access the method UserAccount.SignIn if the method ISN'T declared as static.

If I declare the variable **_httpContextAccessor** as so:

```
private static IHttpContextAccessor
```

rather than:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor
```

all errors go away, but I get a null reference exception on the await statement again.  (the _httpContextAccessor isn't set to an instance of an object)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You access the HttpContext like this:

```
@if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

No directives or packages needed.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, only getting access to it in view, not in code.

Answer (score 6):

I think you intend to look at the *current* HttpContext.  For this, you need to add a dependency for `IHttpContextAccessor` to your controller constructor, then use the `HttpContext` property of that interface in your action method to access the current context.

You may have to register

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

in your Startup.cs, depending on whether or not you already have this service added by other common services that may depend on it.

Comment: I'm using the httpcontext in my controller by only adding the using statement: **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;**
I created a class to simplify the code in the controller methods and in the class is where I'm having trouble using the HttpContext.

Comment: You are statically referencing the class `HttpContext` by using that method, which is causing that error.  You need an *instance* of `HttpContext`, not the static class reference.

Comment: I implemented the IHttpContextAccessor and registered the service.  I literally get the same exact error if I make the function static.  If it's not static, I can't access the method of the class inside the controller where I'm calling it from.

Comment: @tocoolforscool : were you able to find a soln for this. I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting this error

You can't access an instance member from a static member. You may want to read up on [static members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.140).aspx).

> The error disappears if I don't declare the method as static

Yes, because an instance method can access an instance field.

> however from my controllers I can't access the method UserAccount.SignIn if the method ISN'T declared as static.

Sure they can - but they need an *instance*:

```
private UserAccount _userAccount;
ControllerConstructor(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
  _userAccount = new UserAccount(accessor);
}

...
// Inside an action method:
await _userAccount.SignIn(user);
```

> If I declare the variable _httpContextAccessor [as static], all errors go away

Yes, because a static method can access a static field.

> but I get a null reference exception on the await statement again.

Because the static field is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Register the `HttpContextAccessor` in Startup:

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Then to get the current user:

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var currentContext = scope.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    return currentContext.HttpContext.User;
}
```

Comment: what is "host" and can it be accessed outside of a controller?

Comment: @rdans I don't think so